# Copy cells from a Worksheet to another Worksheet (from different Workbooks and first empty cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the content from a user opened worksheet to another worksheet from another Workbook. The code below do works, but it doesnt select the first empty cell from the WS_REL sheet, and overwrite all the data contained. So far, I have this:

```
Sub Importar_Dados()

Dim vTemp As Variant
Dim WB_TOA As Workbook, WB_REL As Workbook
Dim WS_TOA As Worksheet, WS_REL As Worksheet

Set WB_REL = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS_REL = WB_REL.Sheets("Planilha2")

vTemp = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Selecione o relatório gerado pelo TOA", , False)

If TypeName(vTemp) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vTemp

Set WB_TOA = Workbooks.Open(vTemp)
Set WS_TOA = WB_TOA.Sheets("Page 1")

WS_TOA.Cells.Copy WS_REL.Cells

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you dont need to open the other workbook twice. Remove the line

> ```
> Workbooks.Open vTemp
> ```

Then, to append without overwriting, you need to find the last non-empty cell in your destination sheet. Try it like (*for example*):

```
WS_TOA.usedRange.Copy WS_REL.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

If you dont have a column that is sure to have data in all rows, use this:

```
WS_TOA.usedRange.Copy WS_REL.Range("A" & WS_REL.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row+1)
```

This finds you the first non-empty row.

Comment: I would use the `Find` in this example to find the last row with data, more reliable. Since you can't be sure which column has the highest row number with data.

Comment: @ShaiRado I fully agree, but was waiting the OP's feedback, that why *"for example"*

Comment: @RafaelTorres it would be good to take nt of Shai's remark. The snippet supposes that your column "A" has data in all rows. You're welcome.

Comment: How it would be then, Shai?

Comment: @RafaelTorres In that case you can use the added last part in my answer.

Comment: @A.S.H it worked too! Thank you all for the help :). Just for a better understanding, why are you using 4 commas after the `find`?

Comment: @RafaelTorres to set the corresponding parameters of the function to their default values.